# Django Application deployment on linux server

Tags: python, django, configuration, mod-wsgi

I am trying to deploy `django` application on `Linux` server with `mod_wsgi`.

Below are my setting for apache in httpd.conf file -

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
LogLevel warn
ServerName myappletrade.com
#WSGIProcessGroup appletrade
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/appletrade/django.wsgi
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/appletrade
#WSGIDaemonProcess frontend user=vasim group=www
ServerAlias myappletrade.com 
CustomLog /var/www/html/appletrade/access_log   combined
ErrorLog /var/www/html/appletrade/error_log
<Directory /var/www/html/appletrade>
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

django.wsgi file settings -

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, "appletrade")
sys.path.insert(0, "/var/www/html/appletrade/noneapp/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages" )

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'noneapp.settings.development'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

inside `noneapp` folder I have setting files for development ,production server.

When I am trying to for myappletrade.com in browser nothing happens.it shows 500 internal server error.

I have checked error log . where it's saying -

```
[Sat Mar 30 18:07:55 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=2828): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/appletrade/django.wsgi'.
[Sat Mar 30 18:07:55 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Mar 30 18:07:55 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
[Sat Mar 30 18:07:55 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Sat Mar 30 18:07:55 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in get_response
[Sat Mar 30 18:07:55 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[Sat Mar 30 18:07:55 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 224, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Sat Mar 30 18:07:55 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     if resolver.urlconf_module is None:
[Sat Mar 30 18:07:55 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 323, in urlconf_module
[Sat Mar 30 18:07:55 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Sat Mar 30 18:07:55 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Sat Mar 30 18:07:55 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     __import__(name)
[Sat Mar 30 18:07:55 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/var/www/html/appletrade/noneapp/urls/production.py", line 4, in <module>
[Sat Mar 30 18:07:55 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from noneapp.urls.default import urlpatterns as default_urlpatterns
[Sat Mar 30 18:07:55 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/var/www/html/appletrade/noneapp/urls/default.py", line 6, in <module>
[Sat Mar 30 18:07:55 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     url(r'^catalog/', include('appletrade.urls', namespace = "catalog")),
[Sat Mar 30 18:07:55 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 24, in include
[Sat Mar 30 18:07:55 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
[Sat Mar 30 18:07:55 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Sat Mar 30 18:07:55 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     __import__(name)
[Sat Mar 30 18:07:55 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: No module named urls
```

Please check my configuration setting and Let me know if I am missing something.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what are your logs saying?

Comment: where I can check log? Please let me know. I am new for django... checked /var/www/html/appletrade/error_log  bot no log file there.

Comment: Sorry .. file is there but no log entry :(

Comment: I think there is issue with virtual host setting.It's not accessing code files. SO no error log

Comment: <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080> should be your ip address of the server

Comment: Have you also enabled the site?

Comment: I have replaced with server IP (10.0.0.2). But still not working..This is on my local server on LAN.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to force Python 2.7 to use Python 2.6 libraries.  Your django.wsgi lists the python2.6 site packages in the path, but the errors all list python2.7.

Are you using a virtualenv environment as well? Make sure you're using the python installed in that virtual environment, and not the system version - you will be missing any pip installed packages you have.

Upon further review - you don't have all of your variables defined for mod_wsgi in your VirtualHost configuration, either.

Comment: Thanks.. I am new to python dajango. Just got code from client that I have to deploy on server. I can give you directory structure of project. Please help me to deploy it. I am trying to do this from last 2 days.Please help me. Let me know if we can discuss on chat

Comment: Uncomment WSGIDaemonProcess and the other WSGI variables to start.

In addition, please google search for "django mod_wsgi" - you will find a number of blogs / articles that can get you started. 

Again, your problem is that the python binary under /var/www/html/appletrade/noneapp/env/bin/ is not getting executed by your mod_wsgi configuration.

Lastly - you should not be placing the entire source tree under your document root.

You may have to ask your client for help since they wrote this code with a specific environment in mind.